# Remove OBD socket from Golf 7

Tags: vw, obd-ii, repair, golf

could someone please explain how to remove and replace OBD II socket from Golf 7, ideally with pictures or video? Seems ping in my socket are loose. I have a replacement, but can't get the socket out to replace them.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the new socket have wire pigtails or is it just the socket?

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, this is just a socket with a set of new pins from a chinese eshop

Comment: The reason I ask is, the metal parts on the side you're trying to replace are what holds the pins and keeps connection. If you're using the same parts but sticking them in a new plastic part, you're not going to be doing yourself any good..

Comment: thanks, I understand I have to replace metal pins, I have them already, just don't understand how to take the socket out, tried to search over the Internet, however all videos are about how to locate a plug or replace pins, also tried to use brute force without any result